# Use Consolas font family in lstlisting (the whole document is in Vietnamese)

Tags: listings, languages, fontfamily, inconsolata

I am typing a document in Vietnamese about C++, so of course there will be some code. I will use `lstlisting` environment as it is the best choice for code.

However, the `\ttfamily` (default monospace font) seems to be too wide for me. I want to use Consolas instead. However, `inconsolata` package does not work when there is this line in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
```

or

```
\usepackage[vietnamese=nohyphenation]{hyphsubst}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
```

Without one of these, all Vietnamese letters (like `ể` or `ồ`) will disappear in the PDF, though `inconsolata` works.

I am using `pdfLaTeX`. I know that I can change to `XeLaTeX` to type in Consolas easily, but it seems to be a bit too complicated for me to convert a preamble from `pdfLaTeX` to `XeLaTeX`. I've tried four or five times without success.

Anyone can give me some idea? Thank you very much in advance!

Here is my shortened preamble if you can convert it to `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\fontfamily{zi4}\selectfont,}
...
```

My full code can be found [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/zqynsbnftfdq).

Comment: Don't point to an external document. Copy a full small example here.

Comment: Just as a pointer for the utf8 characters (you refer to as "Vietnamese letters"): Have a look at the `literate` option to get them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said you would be willing to try Xe-/LuaLaTeX, I have made an attempt to convert the part that you ask about to LuaLaTeX (involving a font change to the Palatino-like TeX Gyre Pagella).

`listings` may still handle your unicode sequences ("Vietnamese letters") badly, so you should use the `literate` option.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[vietnamese=nohyphenation]{hyphsubst}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{marvosym} %For emoji
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setmonofont{Inconsolata}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{3ex}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=black,      
    urlcolor=darkscarlet,
    citecolor=darkscarlet
}
\urlstyle{tt}
\definecolor{darkscarlet}{rgb}{0.34, 0.01, 0.1}
\definecolor{ultramarineblue}{rgb}{0.25, 0.4, 0.96}
\definecolor{alizarin}{rgb}{0.82, 0.1, 0.26}
\definecolor{cadmiumgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.42, 0.24}
\definecolor{desertsand}{rgb}{0.93, 0.79, 0.69}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},   
    commentstyle=\color{alizarin},
    keywordstyle=\color{ultramarineblue},
    stringstyle=\color{cadmiumgreen},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,%\ttfamily,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2,
    language=C++,
    frame=single
}
\lstset{style=mystyle}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}
Một cái code đơn giản trong C++: (\textit{A simple code written in C++:})
\begin{lstlisting}
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout<<"Hello World!";
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you plan to use Vietnamese characters in listings (for comments, I guess), I'd recommend using `minted`.

There are a few monospaced fonts that support the T5 (Vietnamese) encoding. Here are some examples, the last one is `inconsolata` that, however, lacks support for Vietnamese, so it's not apt for the purpose.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

%%% this is only for the inconsolata example
\makeatletter
\define@key{FV}{fontencoding}%
  {\ifstrempty{#1}%
    {\let\FV@FontEncoding\relax}%
    {\ifstrequal{#1}{none}%
      {\let\FV@FontEncoding\relax}%
      {\def\FV@FontEncoding{\fontencoding{#1}}}}}
 \expandafter\def\expandafter\FV@SetupFont\expandafter{%
   \expandafter\FV@FontEncoding\FV@SetupFont}
 \fvset{fontencoding=none}
\makeatother
%%% end

%%% this is only for the txtt example
\makeatletter
\input{t5txtt.fd}
\DeclareFontShape{T5}{txtt}{m}{it}{<->ssub * txtt/m/sl}{}
\makeatother
%%% end

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{TXTT}

\setminted{fontfamily=txtt}

\begin{minted}{cpp}
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout<<"Hello World!";
}
// Một cái code đơn giản trong C++
\end{minted}

\subsubsection*{LMTT}

\setminted{fontfamily=lmtt}

\begin{minted}{cpp}
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout<<"Hello World!";
}
// Một cái code đơn giản trong C++
\end{minted}

\subsubsection*{QCR}

\setminted{fontfamily=qcr}

\begin{minted}{cpp}
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout<<"Hello World!";
}
// Một cái code đơn giản trong C++
\end{minted}

\subsubsection*{ZLMTT}

\setminted{fontfamily=zlmtt}

\begin{minted}{cpp}
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout<<"Hello World!";
}
// Một cái code đơn giản trong C++
\end{minted}

\subsubsection*{ZI4}

\fvset{fontencoding=T1}
\setminted{fontfamily=zi4}

\begin{minted}{cpp}
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout<<"Hello World!";
}
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]